# A question about 3D Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, 3d, angle

[image]

The questions I am stumped on are parts c) and d).
I am bewildered as to which triangles I am meant to use. For context, I have got an answer of 54.7 for part b and this is correct.

Solutions to c and d are below:

**Solutions**

c) 35 degrees
d) 24 degrees

I would really appreciate any help about where I am going wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: first question: first angle is 56.3 and second angle is 46.7.

Comment: Your diagram has two points labeled "B"!

Comment: Also in the second picture there is something wrong with the nomenclature and the perspective sizes of the sides of the cuboid ahah

Comment: Your post seems to consist of two exercises which need to be completed.  Please ask only one question at a time.  Also, as @mjw states, your first image has two points labeled $B$---please correct the image (this is a pretty simple fix in, for example, MS Paint or Apple's Preview.app).  Your not at the top does not tell us *which* point should be $C$ (though we can figure it out from context below, it is still confusing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cross section through points A, F and M by a plane containing these points, is triangle AMF which gives first angle $\alpha$:

$\tan (\alpha)=\frac{15}{10}=1.4\Rightarrow \alpha=56.3$

In cross section through points A, B and M by a plane containing these points, is triangle AMB which gives first angle $\beta$:

$\tan (\beta)=\frac{15}{\sqrt{10^2+10^2}}=1.06 \Rightarrow \beta= 46.7$

Second question:

a):

$AG=\sqrt{AB^2+BC^2+CG^2}=\sqrt{4^2+4^2+8^2}=9.7$

b):Consider a plane contanig vertices A,C,E and G. we have right angled triangles AGC and AGE.

$tan(\gamma)=\frac8{\sqrt{4^2+4^2}}=1.41\Rightarrow \gamma=54.7$

c):Angle between AG and EFGH is equale to angle between AG and ABCD:

$\theta=\gamma=54.7$

d):

$AH^2=AE^2+EH^2=4^2+8^2=80 \Rightarrow AH=4\sqrt 5$

$\tan (\alpha)=\frac 4{4\sqrt 5}=0.447\Rightarrow \alpha= 24^o$

Comment: why, for part c of the 2nd question, is the answer: (90-part b) i.e. 90-54.7? I do not understand this is and was wondering if you could offer any clarification please. Thank you.

Comment: surely, the two angles form alternate angles and are therefore both equal to 54.7? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @dubstep,You are right. the correct answer to c is  54.7 , I edited the answer. $35^o$ is angle between AG and GC. May be the author of question gave wrong answer.